# FileMaker Pro - Loop data

Tags: excel, filemaker

I have an excel sheet where I am pulling and names, email and password but I would like to loop the 20 entries per excel file so when I print the FileMaker Pro entry I am not wasting paper.

How do I have FMP loop and display multiple values instead of just one.

This is what I currently have but I would like to have more displayed and not just one entry.

[image]

Comment: You can use math to position the data on the sheet. Why are you printing a password?

Comment: math to position the data? First time ever using FMP. These are for the students so they and teachers will have their passwords. (elementary kids)

Comment: How is this related to Filemaker?

Comment: Because I am using FMP to display content?

Comment: You said you have an Excel sheet. It's difficult to understand what your question is really about. If your data is inside Filemaker (i.e. you have imported the Excel sheet), then this question is not about Excel.

Comment: Oh, never knew I made the question sound about excel. I never added the excel tag, someone else did. *shrug*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is to create a new layout for printing and select "List view" as the layout type. The rest should be pretty obvious as you follow the New Layout/Report assistant.

Before printing, go to the printing layout and find the records you want to print. This can (and should) be scripted.

---

Note also that if you switch your current layout to List view, you will be able to print several records per page (as many as will fit on a page given the height of the body part).